# Calling RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, action, redirecttoaction

I have a form that calls this action to build the CompareEvents page:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CompareEvents(int[] EventsList, bool showIndex, bool showFRN, bool showProvider)
{
        var viewModel = new EventsListViewModel
        {
            Events = EventsList,
            ShowFRN = showFRN,
            ShowIndex = showIndex,
            ShowProvider = showProvider
        };

        return View(viewModel);
}
```

in the CompareEvents view there is another form that allows the user to update information:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateSolution(IEnumerable<Solution> sol)
    {

            //update solution code
            int[] eventList = { '85' };

            return RedirectToAction("CompareEvents", new { EventsList = eventList, showIndex = true, showFRN = true, showProvider = true });
}
```

When this information is update, I would like to reload the page.  I plan on doing this by calling the CompareEvents action again, however my stacktrace is saying that `A public action method 'CompareEvents' was not found on controller`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are both actions defined in the same controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot redirect to an action that is marked `[HttpPost]`. `RedirectToAction` uses a GET.

**Source:**

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action.

[Reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)